# SqlXml removes XML header when comes from string

Tags: c#, xml, string, sqlxml

I'm developing a web app with C# and MVC4. Currently I'm working in converting **string vars to SqlXml files**. I have a XML file with this structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cfdi:Comprobante xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv32.xsd http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital/TimbreFiscalDigital.xsd" xmlns:tfd="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital" version="3.2" xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
</cfdi:Comprobante>
```

I'm converting the above file to string successfully and then I'm usign the following code that converts a string to a **SqlXML**.

```
cfdiDocumento.CFDIXML = Serializar.XMLToSqlXml(comprobante);
```

Where **cfdiDocumento.CFDIXML** is a **SqlXml var**,  **Serializar.XMLToSqlXml(comprobante)** method receives a string and executes the following code:

```
    public static SqlXml XMLToSqlXml(string xmlString)
    {
        SqlXml sqlXmlFiltro = null;
        if (xmlString != null)
        {
            StringReader sr = new StringReader(xmlString);
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Auto;
            XmlReader reader0 = XmlReader.Create(sr, settings);
            sqlXmlFiltro = new SqlXml(reader0);
        }

        return sqlXmlFiltro;
    }
```

When the code finishes successfully, the file is correct but is removing the **xml header**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

The question is: **How do I preserve the xml header when convierting to SqlXml var?**

Comment: What makes you think that `SqlXml` is to blame? Perhaps it's your conversion function and the use of `XmlReader` that removes the XML prologue...?

Comment: How are you displaying the XML?  The XML display tool in VS doesn't show the identification line even though it is there.

Comment: @jdweng I'm storing the generated XML file in Windows Azure Storage, when I download the file it doesn't have the header.

Comment: @stakx Thanks for your advice, I'll debug that part and comment what was the outcome.

Comment: [because the following information is not retained: insignificant white spaces, order of attributes, namespace prefixes, and XML declaration.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh403385.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot change the type of your SqlXml attribute, you could try converting the SqlXml to xml document to append xml declaration and get the outer xml:

```
public string SqlXmlToString(SqlXml sqlXml)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(sqlXml.CreateReader());

    // Create XML declaration with your encoding. 
    XmlDeclaration xmldecl;
    xmldecl = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", null, null);
    xmldecl.Encoding = "UTF-8";

    // Add to the document the created declaration
    XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
    doc.InsertBefore(xmldecl, root);

    return doc.OuterXml;
}
```

Hope this is helpfully